# Incrementing the ID in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework and I have an id (ChargerTypeID) in the database which has a binary system increment (i.e the first ID is 1 the second is 2 the third is 4...etc) I want to run a code that increments the ID*2 when creating a new charger in the database.

Comment: Are you using Code First or Database First?

Comment: am using my own database

Comment: I'll take that as "Database First". As long as your database field has Identity set, and this is reflected in your generated EDMX model, EF should do it all for you. Have you tried leaving it out of your Create method and seeing if it works?

Comment: the problem is the ID is not auto incremented

Comment: OK, is there a requirement that means it can't be created as an Identity? If so you will have to run a separate query to get the largest integer value from that column, and incremented it by 1.

Comment: I want to retrieve the latest entry and multiply it b 2

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it's quite hard to really understand your setup.

However, from what I do understand you will probably need to run another query to get your latest ID with EF, then do the math and re-insert it as an integer.

So something like..

```
var largestId = Context.yourTable.OrderByDescending(u => u.ChargerTypeID).First().ChargerTypeID;
var newId = (largestId  * 2 );
```

Comment: I need to do this action in the controller

Comment: You will need to do this in a transaction or you could end up with two of the same id.